# Converting parsed string values to float

Tags: bokeh, geopandas

Using Geopandas with Bokeh, I am visualizing a GIS dataset which also has location elevations. The elevation values are of Double type, originating from the Shapefile I am loading, e.g. '1382.770000'.

When displaying these values to the user (say, using the HoverTool), they are presented in their exponential form, e.g. for the example above 1.382e+3.

As the code is user-oriented / interactive, I would like to display those figures in a simplified float format - can this be achieved?

I have tried:

```
hover = HoverTool (tooltips = [('Elevation', float('@elev')])
```

However this brings a *ValueError: could not convert string to float: '@elev'*

Code example:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import json

import bokeh.io
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import GeoJSONDataSource, HoverTool

# prevent Bokeh from savig sketch into file / opening in a new tab
bokeh.io.reset_output()
bokeh.io.output_notebook()

shapefile = 'data/USA Counties 20m/cb_2017_us_county_20m_with_cZone_USAF_coordinates_elevations.shp'

#Read shapefile using Geopandas
gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)[['CZONE', 'NAME', 'geometry','USAF','xcoord','ycoord','ELEV_IN_M']]

#Rename columns.
gdf.columns = ['cZone', 'Name', 'geometry','USAF','Long','Lat','elev']

#Reset index
gdf = gdf.reset_index(drop=True)

#Read data to json.
json_raw = json.loads(gdf.to_json())

#Convert to String like object.
json_data = json.dumps(json_raw)

#Input GeoJSON source that contains features for plotting.
geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json_data)


#Add hover tools
hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [ ('Climate Zone','@cZone'),
                               ('County','@Name'),
                               ('USAF','@USAF'),
                               ('elev','@elev')])

#Create figure object.
p = figure(title = 'USA Climate Zone Map by County', plot_height = 450 , plot_width = 800, toolbar_location = "below")
p.add_tools(hover)

#Add patch renderer to figure. 
p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource, 
          line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1)

# Display figure & widget
show(p)
```

the shapefile can be reached [here](https://app.box.com/s/nabtin0a0azm6zfb759ngp15wsdtjeos)

Comment: What library are you using for the visualization? Can you provide a full, reproducible code example?

Comment: Using Bokeh for the visualization. I've updated the post with more information as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tooltips formatting like this (Bokeh v1.1.0):

```
hover = HoverTool(tooltips = [ ('Climate Zone', '@cZone'),
                               ('County', '@Name'),
                               ('USAF', '@USAF'),
                               ('elev', '@{elev}{%0.3f}') ],
                  formatters = {'elev' : 'printf'} )
```

[image]